# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I always get the following error once I retrieved records with integer data type from my database using my combobox:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

It works when I replace my query and retrieve records that has varchar data type.

Can someone please help me how to modify my code to get the expected output?

Here is my code:

```
public void fillSupplier()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STATION21\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true");
    conn.Open();
    string query = "Select supID from Supplier";
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query,conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        cmbSupp.DataSource = dt;
        cmbSupp.DisplayMember = "supID";
        cmbSupp.ValueMember = "supID";
    }
}

private void cmbSupp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STATION21\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true");
    conn.Open();
    this.Refresh();
    string query = "Select * from Supplier where supID='"+cmbSupp.Text+"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read()) { 
        tbsName.Text = dr["supName"].ToString();
        tbsContact.Text = dr["supLocation"].ToString();
        tbsLoc.Text = dr["supContact"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with this *(removed the single apostrophes, which indicate a string literal)*:

```
string query = "Select * from Supplier where supID = " + cmbSupp.Text;
```

Also, look into parameterizing your query. You'll be far less likely to run into issues like this, especially when the query you're executing has many parameters.

```
string query = "Select * from Supplier where supID = @supID";
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supID", int.Parse(cmbSupp.Text));
```

Here's some [good reading material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with examples.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. how can i fix it?

Comment: this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(cmbSupp.Text));

Comment: this is my code for cmbSupp.

          

            string query = "Select supID from Supplier";
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query,conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {

                cmbSupp.DataSource = dt;
                cmbSupp.DisplayMember = "supID";
                cmbSupp.ValueMember = "supID";